In cable TV, what prevents an user added channel from propagating downstream?
A cable TV user can use an RF modulator and a coaxial splitter/combiner to add a video signal, in an unused channel, to the coaxial cables running in their home.
What prevents this new channel to propagate outside the home into the neighbour's home? Or to propagate to the next amplifier in the line and then reach every home downstream?
Simple coaxial splitter/combiners seem to have no directionality thus sending the new channel to all inputs/outputs.
Do cable companies have a device in their infrastructure to prevent this?

They will trace the signal and throw you in jail.

CATV splitters are directional, that is they couple the output ports to the input ports but not to each other so much
So a signal presented to one of the output ports will flow mostly to the input port. (so it wont flow down the line only up it)
Then at the next splitter it comes in through the main output port (so same problem again)
Finally it reaches an amplifier and the amplifiers output port absorbs it. Amplifiers are very directional.

RF amplifiers are one-way devices. Like all amplifiers, you can't back-feed a signal through an amplifier to it's source. It's a one-way street.

CATV is digital encrypted 256-bit QAM, not analog. Your CATV modem is not going to convert to 256-bit QAM or send it anywhere except to digital he11
